# Python reload() not re-loading class implementation?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a module structure like the following:

```
.
└── testmodule
    ├── __init__.py
    └── submodule
        ├── __init__.py
        └── implementation.py

2 directories, 3 files
```

Here are the contents of each file

```
# testmodule/__init__.py
import submodule
```

```
# testmodule/submodule/__init__.py
from implementation import *
```

```
# testmodule/submodule/implementation.py
class Car(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.doors = 2
        self.color = 'red'
```

Why does the class implementation not "reload" when I use `reload()` as in the following test?

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Oct 11 2016, 05:24:00)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import testmodule
>>> car = testmodule.submodule.Car()
>>> car.doors
2
>>> # I edit the file and change self.doors = 2 to self.doors = 4
>>> reload(testmodule)
<module 'testmodule' from 'testmodule/__init__.pyc'>
>>> car = testmodule.submodule.Car()
>>> car.doors
2
>>> # no more edits made before the Python REPL is restarted

me@laptop # python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Oct 11 2016, 05:24:00)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import testmodule
>>> car = testmodule.submodule.Car()
>>> car.doors
4
```

**Update**

By @wim's logic, I would have to reload `testmodule.submodule.implementation`, then reload `testmodule.submodule` to make this "work", and indeed that is the case. See these tests:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Oct 11 2016, 05:24:00)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import testmodule
>>> c = testmodule.submodule.Car()
>>> c.doors
2
>>> # I edit the file and change self.doors = 2 to self.doors = 4
>>> reload(testmodule.submodule.implementation)
<module 'testmodule.submodule.implementation' from 'testmodule/submodule/implementation.py'>
>>> c = testmodule.submodule.Car()
>>> c.doors
2
>>> reload(testmodule.submodule)
<module 'testmodule.submodule' from 'testmodule/submodule/__init__.pyc'>
>>> c = testmodule.submodule.Car()
>>> c.doors
4

me@laptop # python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Oct 11 2016, 05:24:00)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import testmodule
>>> c = testmodule.submodule.Car()
>>> c.doors
2
>>> # I edit the file and change self.doors = 2 to self.doors = 4
>>> reload(testmodule.submodule)
<module 'testmodule.submodule' from 'testmodule/submodule/__init__.pyc'>
>>> c = testmodule.submodule.Car()
>>> c.doors
2
>>> reload(testmodule.submodule.implementation)
<module 'testmodule.submodule.implementation' from 'testmodule/submodule/implementation.py'>
>>> c = testmodule.submodule.Car()
>>> c.doors
2
>>> reload(testmodule.submodule)
<module 'testmodule.submodule' from 'testmodule/submodule/__init__.pyc'>
>>> c = testmodule.submodule.Car()
>>> c.doors
4
```

Comment: `reload` is far less thorough than people usually expect. This is only one of the ways in which it doesn't reload everything you'd want it to reload. It's usually better to just restart Python.

Comment: By the way, it's unrelated to your issue, but the line `from implementation import *`, and also the line `import submodule`, are very bad practice.  These are implicit relative imports, and your code will stop working properly on Python 3.

Comment: @wim thanks, I need to read more about Python 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR that's expected behaviour of reload.

### Why it happens?

Importing `testmodule` actually loads the subpackages into `sys.modules`:

```
>>> import testmodule
>>> [m for m in sys.modules if m.startswith('testmodule')]
['testmodule.submodule', 'testmodule.submodule.implementation', 'testmodule']
```

Now, when you reload `testmodule`, it will pickup changes in the implementation of `testmodule` directly - i.e. any lines changed in `testmodule/__init__.py`.

However, you didn't change any lines there, and the `submodule` name which `testmodule` holds a reference will still point to the old unchanged `submodule`.

Basically, the meta-answer is that you overestimated how smart "reload" is about things.  You can implement a deep-reload which hooks into subpackages, but it's pretty hard to do correctly, and I would advise you not to bother.

### What can you do about it?

IPython made some attempts in that direction, if you're interested:

```
# Python 2
import __builtin__
from IPython.lib import deepreload
__builtin__.reload = deepreload.reload
```

(see [`IPython.lib.deepreload`](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.lib.deepreload.html#module-IPython.lib.deepreload) for more information).

Comment: Thank you for the information, see my edits to the question.

Comment: As I use the `IPython` REPL, starting up and then running `from IPython.lib.deepreload import reload` is a good solution for me, and actually fixes the issue that I was having in this case.

Comment: I've already run into an issue caused by a stateful `__init__.py` when using this technique. So, I'm going back to restarting Python, which is a pain.

Comment: Yep.  There's a reason no one uses reload...it sucks!  ;)